# Change own class base name to add to listboxitem

Tags: c#, winforms

I have object `Audio` with Properties "Title", "Artist" and so on.
I add it to `ListboxItem` and Content becomes

> {audio202738880_386844236}

Here is [screenshot](http://monosnap.com/image/Gz3KbsETxtHHpoRadEAUAHO5IRaxB8)

How change this base: {audio202738880_386844236} to value what i want (ex audio.Artist + " - " audio.Title)?

Comment: Does the `Audio` is your class?

Comment: @ArtemKulikov its VkNet library. I installed it with Nuget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several ways to do it.
If `Audio` is your class - you should override `ToString` function:

```
public override string ToString()
{
   return string.Format("{0}_{1}", Artist, Title);
}
```

If no and you use WinForms - you should implement function [DrawItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem(v=vs.110).aspx) and redraw `ListBox` by yourself. Also, don't forget to change property [`DrawMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawmode(v=vs.110).aspx) to value `DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed`. It shows, that all the elements in the `listbox` control are drawn manually.

```
private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
   // Draw the background of the ListBox control for each item.
   e.DrawBackground();

   // Draw the current item text
   var currentItem = listBox1.Items[e.Index] as Audio;
   var outputStr = string.Format("{0}_{1}", currentItem.Artist, currentItem.Title);
   e.Graphics.DrawString(outputStr, e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);

   // If the ListBox has focus, draw a focus rectangle around the selected item.
   e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

Actually if you use WPF - you have third variant. But problem is that fields `Title` and `Artist` should have accessors methods.. If your class doesn't have it - it doesn't work.
First of all you should set `ItemsSource`

```
listBox1.ItemsSource = YourList<Artist>();
```

Next - use the ListBox's [ItemTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) property:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <WrapPanel>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Artist}" />
         <TextBlock Text="_" />
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" />
      </WrapPanel>
   </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Last variant, if your fields don't have accessors. The one way you have - is to inherit a class and implement `ToString` as I said:

```
public class MyAudio : Audio
{
   public override string ToString()
   {
      return string.Format("{0}_{1}", Artist, Title);
   }
}
```

Comment: It's not my own class

Comment: Yep, I added second variant for you. You should use `DrawItem` void from `ListBox`.

Comment: No. You need it for WPF?

Comment: Yes. Can you change it?

Comment: Good, wpf variant working well. But how to add iteration before <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Artist}" /> Ex: 1. Artist _ Title

Answer (score 1):

You have to override the `ToString()` method. This method is used to determine what is shown in the Listbox.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return "Whatever You can construct";
}
```

You would construct the return value from the properties in your class to make a sensible string representation of the object.

If it is not directly your class, you might create your own that inherits from the `Audio` class, put the override in there and use that new class instead in your code. It will behave exactly the same, with exception of the `ToString()` function. This only works if `Audio` is not marked as `sealed` though.

```
public class MyAudio : Audio
{

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Whatever You can construct";
    }
}
```

---

**Added by Moe Farag**

You may need to mark `ToString()` as `new` if there is already an `override` of the base class implementation. However, you have to be sure to use the child class (`MyAudio` in this case) whenever you use the `ToString()` method, in order for the new implementation to be used.

```
public class MyAudio : Audio
{

    public new string ToString()
    {
        return "Whatever You can construct";
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not my own class